# Backup or replicate one sql server to another

Tags: sql-server, backup, replication

I have 2 instances of SQL server running on 2 separate servers; let's call them sql1 and sql2.

How do I make sure that one database in sql1 is backed up to sql2 at least nightly?

I know nothing about this, so if you could point me to a good tutorial, that would help immensely.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd read this article from technet magazine: [Achieve High Availability for SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.03.highavailability.aspx) It sounds like (from what you've asked for so far) that log shipping will do what you need it to do.  Take a look at this article on how to set-up log shipping: [Configuring Log Shipping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188698(SQL.90).aspx).